# Substitution of a string with another string

Tags: unix, sed

can anybody please tell me what does this command precisely do :

```sh
sed -e 's/(return status = 0)//g'  -e 's/\-//g' | sed 's/ //g'
```

I am not able to understand which string does this command substitute and with what string as I am new to UNIX.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- look for `(return status = 0)`
- delete it
- look for `-`
- delete it
- look for
- delete it